# how to get keycloak token with angular

Tags: angular, keycloak

i'm using keycloak and angular 5, i'm trying to get to tooken, i folowed the keyxloak doc and heres te code :

```
getTokenKeyCloak() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers  = headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


    let data = {
        client_id :'admin-cli',
        username  :'**',
        password  :'**',
        grant_type : 'password'
    };
        return this.http
            .post("auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",data, {headers:headers})

        .map((res: Response) => {
            alert('hello');


        }).catch(this.handleError);

}
```

every time i send the request, i got this message :

> Backend returned code 400, body was: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing form parameter: grant_type"}

Comment: Debug it (browser f12) and see what's being sent in the form.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little late but maybe someone is still looking for the answer.
This works:

```js
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })};

    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: 'myclient',
        username: username,
        password: password,
        scope: 'openid'
      }
    });

    return this.http.post('/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token', params, httpOptions)
      .pipe(tap((response: any) => {
        this.tokeninfo = jwtDecode(response.access_token);
      }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `client_secret`. Curl example:

```
curl \
  -d "client_id=myclient" \
  -d "client_secret=40cc097b-2a57-4c17-b36a-8fdf3fc2d578" \
  -d "username=user" \
  -d "password=password" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

Doc: http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/securing_apps/topics/oidc/oidc-generic.html

However `client_secret` is exposed in this case. So this is not the best option for Angular. A better choice is to use Implicit Flow. Example library for Angular: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client